# Is there an easier way to print taxonomies in the tpl? I get this working code, but it should be a "shorter" way!

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, performance

After a painful day and a half I get this code, that prints out in my node.tpl.php the taxonomy terms associated to that particular node that the user is viewing.

It works just fine. As it is quite long I´ll just put the whole thing inside a module and into a variable, to just print that.

The thing is that it should get an easier, better way to do this!
Any ideas?

```
<?php 
$vid = 11; //vocabulary id
$nid = $node->nid; //it looks for the current loaded node
$query = "SELECT tid, name
FROM (
SELECT td.tid AS tid, name
FROM taxonomy_term_data AS td
JOIN taxonomy_index AS tn
  ON td.tid = tn.tid
JOIN node AS n
  ON n.nid = tn.nid
WHERE td.vid = ". $vid ."
  AND n.status = 1
  AND n.nid = ".$nid."
GROUP BY td.tid
) AS t
ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = db_query($query);
foreach($result as $term) {
      echo l($term->name, "taxonomy/term/$term->tid") . ', ';
}
 ?>
```

## **UPDATE:**

This is devel output:
(I´ve used (`dpm($node);`) because it let me print the result here without losing the indentation)

```
(object) array(
  'vid' => '5178',
  'uid' => '1',
  'title' => 'PROYECTO',
  'log' => '',
  'status' => '1',
  'comment' => '2',
  'promote' => '0',
  'sticky' => '0',
  'nid' => '155',
  'type' => 'jornadas',
  'language' => 'und',
  'created' => '1095048000',
  'changed' => '1360589684',
  'tnid' => '0',
  'translate' => '0',
  'revision_timestamp' => '1360589684',
  'revision_uid' => '1',
  'taxonomy_vocabulary_4' => array(),
  'taxonomy_vocabulary_6' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'tid' => '33',
        'taxonomy_term' => (object) array(
            'tid' => '33',
            'vid' => '6',
            'name' => 'Jornadas Gratuitas',
            'description' => '',
            'format' => NULL,
            'weight' => '0',
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'vocabulary_6',
          ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'taxonomy_vocabulary_7' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'tid' => '40',
        'taxonomy_term' => (object) array(
            'tid' => '40',
            'vid' => '7',
            'name' => 'Para PH',
            'description' => '',
            'format' => NULL,
            'weight' => '-10',
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'vocabulary_7',
          ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'taxonomy_vocabulary_11' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'tid' => '262',
        'taxonomy_term' => (object) array(
            'tid' => '262',
            'vid' => '11',
            'name' => 'colegios',
            'description' => '',
            'format' => NULL,
            'weight' => '0',
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'vocabulary_11',
          ),
      ),
      array(
        'tid' => '543',
        'taxonomy_term' => (object) array(
            'tid' => '543',
            'vid' => '11',
            'name' => 'derecho',
            'description' => '',
            'format' => NULL,
            'weight' => '0',
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'vocabulary_11',
          ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'body' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'value' => "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things here:

1. Your SQL is open to [injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
2. You're running a query that has already been run, and for which data has already been returned by the core field system. Drupal already runs way too many queries in a page load, adding another unnecessary one should be avoided wherever possible.
3. Your code should be in a template preprocess function (or module file as you've mentioned). But that's not because of the *length* of the code. It's because you should maintain a good separation of logic and display.
4. Drupal has already prepared the display of the field for you, so it would be preferable to use that instead of building up from scratch again.

With those in mind, try simply adding:

```
<?php echo render($content['field_name_of_term_ref_field']); ?>
```

in place of your code.

To control how those field items come out (e.g. as links), navigate to admin/structure/types/manage/TYPE/display, and choose appropriate settings for the display widget.

Comment: Are you sure it's set to display on the "Manage Display" tab of your content type?

Comment: Sorry, By mistake I´ve deleted the comment! I´ll check that out now.

Comment: Yes, they all should display, I´ve just checked the "Manage display" tab. And no, sadly that code doesn´t print out anything. This was the link being referenced by me in my accidentally deleted comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835303/printing-all-array-results-in-a-themable-way-using-php

Comment: The only way they get printed is with this: print render($content['taxonomy_vocabulary_11'][0]['#title']); (I need to print out each one [0], [1], [2], etc). And even when they should get printed like links (in Manage Display I´ve set them that way), they are printed out in plain text.

Comment: Hmm is this a custom content type or one provided by a contrib module? If you've added the field yourself it should definitely start with `field_`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It´s a custom content type. And the machine name is taxonomy_vocabulary_11 (this is a ported D6 site, and that was the taxonomy attached to that node type). I´ve tried also: field_vocabulary_11 and field_taxonomy_vocabulary_11, with no luck.

Comment: Here´s the devel output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835303/printing-all-array-results-in-a-themable-way-using-php

Comment: Ahhh ok. I remember seeing questions of yours before using D6 so I did wonder :) I can't think why the field isn't showing, but if you want to force it you can try `print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'taxonomy_vocabulary_11'));`...

Comment: Yes, I´m stuck with this froma  while now :). I´ve printed out this, but it won´t print. I´ve tried other options: $links, wich didn´t worked out either. $terms won´t work because (in any theme) shows notice error: Notice: Undefined variable: term... It´s pretty weird...

Comment: On the Devel tab for the node there's a sub-tab called 'Render'...you should be able to see whats being passed through in there. If you can dump that output to pastebin or something I can take a look

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I´ve pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/tGir5EbF